# What are the hidden rules in Python documents?

Tags: python, random, document

I need to learn Python to do some data manipulation. When I read the documents, the documents out there are written in such a great skill so that I get very frustrated with some hidden message. For instance:

1. in official Python Documents: 
   [`random.sample(population, k)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample)

   What is population? What type of it? According to the following, it seems that it is a list? So, is it the only valid type that the functions receive?
2. in official Numpy Documents: 
   [`numpy.random.random_sample`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.random_sample.html#numpy.random.random_sample)

   The title is `numpy.random.random_sample(size=None)`, and the following paragraph said that

   > size: int or tuple of ints, optional
   >
   > Output shape. If the given shape is, e.g., (m, n, k), then m * n * k samples are drawn.

   What does it mean? So, there are actually 2 parameters, 1st one is size, and the 2nd one is the shape and it is optional? So if I want to pass in 2 parameters, should I write `random.random_sample(5,[m,n,k])` or `random.random_sample(5, m, n k)`?

These documents are very brief and the author seems very shy to demo the usage of the library. It seems that they always try to hide something from us. I wonder if there are some Python customs that I should learn to understand all these magic?

Comment: Python is dynamically typed, so there are several types (e.g. `list`, `tuple`, ...) that can be a `population` - as the docs say, *"sequence or set"*. And in your second example, you want `((m, n, k))`, otherwise you're clearly passing more than the single documented parameter; it's *"int **or** tuple of ints"*. I think this is mainly a reading comprehension problem, rather than hidden rules or magic.

Comment: What jon said. Generally, good Python programmers write functions that will accept any type that makes sense. So `random.sample` will accept for _population_ any sequence type, or indeed any iterable that has a well-defined length. So you can pass it a list, tuple, or even a set. Or your own custom object that can behave like an iterator with a well-defined length.

Comment: Please don't get frustrated. Get Jupyter/IPython notebook instead! Use the internal help and try out things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The type of the population being sampled is, roughly, "iterable". I assume the underlying implementation is doing reservoir sampling, which requires only that the data can be passed through once. You can pass in a tuple if you like.
2. The size parameter may be either an integer or a "shape" (3-tuple) conforming to the docs. The three components of the shape will be multiplied together to give the size. Thus, the function accepts only a single argument.

Python is not statically typed, so there is no fixed type that a particular parameter "must" have, and the called function is free to treat different inputs differently.

There are two examples of calling the function present on the numpy documentation page you linked.

3. I don't see anything wrong with using a simple loop and a call to a random number generator. There's probably a library function, but that would only make the difference between two easy lines of your code and one. No big deal.

Comment: FWIW, the iterable passed to `random.sample` needs to have a length, so you can't pass it a generator, or it raises `TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()`.

Answer (score 0):

Consult the tutorial in the docs, these are basic things you have to be clear about before going further.

Q1. Get familiar with **duck typing**. It's one of the core things in dynamically typed languages like python, ruby etc. It's a duck as long as it quacks. So here the parameter can be **any** sequence or set.

Q2. As long as the receiving function can handle it, it's ok. So if you pass `int` it can handle it and it can also handle a `tuple`. So as far as semantics go, this is great.

Comment: The second one isn't duck typing; they're two different aquatic birds, it's more like polymorphism.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yeah. That's why I didn't copy/paste the first line."receiving function thinks it's a duck.." .Editing it. Thanks.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I would call it bird typing or something.

Comment: BTW, you should check out the [SO Python chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) some time...

Comment: @CPanda *"waterfowl typing"*